# What is the difference between constant and restrict pointers?

Tags: c

What is the difference between constant and restrict pointers, for example:

```
int * const ptr,  int * restrict ptr
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They do completely different things. A `const` pointer will not change. A `restrict` pointer will be the only way in which the object pointed to is accessed.

Comment: C is really amazing. After 15 years, I still get to see corners of it I haven't seen before.

Comment: Typical example: implement `c = a + b` via `void add(float * a, float * b, float * c)`. Without `restrict`, the compiler must assume that `a`, `b` and `c` could all be pointing to the same (or overlapping) regions of memory, while adding `restrict` forbids that and allows a more efficient implementation.

Comment: I don't understand how void add(float * a, float * b, float * c) could be more more efficient it all the add does is  a = *b + *c